# Is it possible to create/add a ZigBee private profile/endpoint/cluster/ for a XBee Series 2 module? How?

Tags: endpoint, xbee, zigbee

I have 2 XBee Series 2 modules configured as Coordinator and End-Device using API mode.

I want to add a my private profile and its cluster into an End-Device module so that when I start discovery on Coordinator side.

I can find my End-Device module and not other nearby ZigBee modules that don't match with my private profile ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to configure the module with `ATAO=3`, and implement portions of the ZDO/ZDP (ZigBee Data Objects/ZigBee Device Profile) on endpoint 0.

If you're using C, you might want to consider a this [cross-platform, Open Source, ANSI C, XBee Host Library](https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library) that I've put a lot of work into.  It includes ZDO and ZCL handling if you're looking to create a ZigBee-compliant XBee-based device.

You'll have to set up an endpoint table with the desired profile ID and cluster IDs you plan to implement.

Comment: I have one problem "Error -110 waiting for query to complete" when running XBee C library's "atinter" sample app. At the beginning, when it's looping to call these 2 functions xbee_dev_tick( &my_xbee); status = xbee_cmd_query_status( &my_xbee); the firmware info can't be queried and always NULL, and therefore the code can't move on. This happens 4 out of 10 times when I hooked the XBee Series 2 module directly to the laptop via USB port.

Comment: What baud rate are you using?  And have you enabled hardware handshaking (RTS and CTS) on the module?

Comment: The problem was that the End-Device was sleeping when it was queried as it was configured to go sleep every 5 seconds. I had to manually press the button to wake it up or make to go to sleep less frequently as a work around. No problem with your code.

Comment: What are ClusterID=0x0011 at EndpointID=0xE8 used for? What are their purposes in this library? I see there are 2 functions written to send data/string to this cluster.

Comment: That's Digi's "transparent serial" cluster. Modules with "AT mode" firmware use it to pass data to/from their serial port without any framing. It is specific to XBee modules and is not a ZigBee standard.

Comment: I have another question regarding API Frame and RSSI to ask you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302777/in-xbee-zigbee-how-to-get-rssi-of-all-end-devices-from-coordinator